# How do I get the parameters from a POST request from a HTML form in Actix-web?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I am building a little webapp in Actix-web, but I can't find any example of getting parameters out of a POST request in Actix-web anywhere.

[Searching their excellent examples repo](https://github.com/actix/examples/search?q=POST&unscoped_q=POST) only gives a [couple](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/a01db994f6af8344669642dae99d58ca1b072189/json/src/main.rs#L118) of (to me) meaningful [examples](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/e4f1833215b4e4ab1deb59484942c499a2deffc3/web-cors/backend/src/main.rs#L35), but they both deal with JSON and not form data.

I also found [this page](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/trait.FromRequest.html), which I suspect holds the answer; but to a beginner this isn't much help.

I imagine it should look something like:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

and

```
fn main() {
    // ...
    App::with_state(AppState { db: pool.clone() })
        .middleware(IdentityService::new(
            CookieIdentityPolicy::new(&[0; 32])
                .name("auth-cookie")
                .secure(true),
        ))
        .resource("/login", |r| {
            r.method(http::Method::GET).with(login);
            r.method(http::Method::POST).with(perform_login) // help!
        })
}

struct LoginParams {
    password: String,
}    

fn perform_login(mut req: HttpRequest<AppState>, params: LoginParams) -> HttpResponse {
    if params.password == "abc123" {
        req.remember("logged-in".to_owned());
        // redirect to home
    };
    // show "wrong password" error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an extractor by:

- Defining a struct that can be deserialized from raw data.
- Defining a handler that accepts an extractor. In your case, use `Form` [as Nikolay said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156992/155423), with the type parameter of your struct.
- Register this handler.

If you take a look at simple example in linked documentation you'll see how describe such handler.

Here is a bit more complete one:

## Define struct

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct AddHook {
    id: u64,
    title: String,
    version: Option<String>,
    code: Option<String>
}
```

## Define handler

```
fn remove_hook_del((query, state): (Form<AddHook>, State<AppState>)) -> FutureHttpResponse {
    let query = query.into_inner();
    let AddHook {id, title, version, code} = query;

    //Do something with your data
}
```

## Register handler

```
App::with_state(AppState::new()).resource("/remove_hook", |res| {
    res.method(Method::GET).with(remove_hook_get);
    res.method(Method::DELETE).with(remove_hook_del);
    res.route().f(not_allowed);
})
```

This is more or less a complete example for [the current master branch of `actix-web`](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/tree/09aabc7b3b23be7c4ae02dada73138b2b57a97e5). I also made it with state to show how you can use multiple arguments in your handler

Answer (score 0):

You need [Form](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.Form.html) extractor.
`params: Form<LoginParams>`

Comment: This may answer the question, but would be more helpful with [evidence](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/206345) to support it.

Comment: I am reading through it, and it seems like it is indeed the answer, and I *almost* understand the example there. I just don't get how it's supposed to access the `req` parameter (like in my example above) when it only gets a `Form`

Comment: I give up for now and work on something else until https://github.com/actix/examples/issues/24 is resolved